# Is an ideal containing the nilradical a radical ideal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

In the book „A course in commutative Algebra“ by Gregor Kemper in Theorem 1.25 (b) the proof states that $A \cong K[…]/I$ and since A is reduced, I is a radical ideal.
But I don’t get why exactly A reduced implies I is a radical Ideal. Can someone help out?

Comment: The answer of the question in the title is obviously $\textbf{No}$. Note that $(X^2)$ contains the nilradical of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ (which is the zero ideal), yet $(X^2)$ is not radical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be reduced means that there aren't any non-zero element whose power is zero. Now, in a quotient ring, element is zero exactly when its representative lies in the ideal. Compare this to the definition of a radical ideal: $\forall x\in I: x^n\in I \implies x\in I$.

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem perfectly. Do you know the answer to the title? So is a Ideal, that contains the Nilradical, a radical ideal?

Comment: @Josef As answered in the comments, containing the nilradical doesn't quarantee an ideal to be radical. But the quotient ring being reduced is a stronger property, in fact equivalent to the ideal being radical.